# Does "physical burden" make sense?

Tags: nouns

> This robot helps to reduce the burden on people who take care of
>   older adults.

I created the sentence above to describe that the robot can enable people with less muscle to take care of older adults more easily. I would like to emphasize that the robot is like a powered exoskeleton and removes physical difficulty rather than emotional/mental difficulty.

I am wondering whether the noun "burden" is appropriate for this case because dictionaries define this term as "[Something that is emotionally difficult to bear](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=burden)".

Comment: That dictionary also defines *burden* as "Something that is carried", so yes, *physical burden* is fine.

Comment: Your sentence is completely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "physical burden" makes sense.

If you exclude the "physical" part, the nature of the burden becomes ambiguous.